# Data source contains an ImpersonationMode that is not supported for processing operations

Tags: sql-server, ssas, analysis, olap, ssas-tabular

hi i am trying to connect the  the data base using visual studo analysis service.

When i process the table i am getting this error:

"SSAS Tabular Project - Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'Data source contains an ImpersonationMode that is not supported for processing operations.
A connection could not be made to the data source with the Name of 'SqlServe'"

Anyone have any idea  how i can connect and process?

[image]

Comment: is your data source connection successful in the project ?

Comment: yes @VenkataramanR

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, use the option "Specific Windows user name and password" in the "Impersonation Information" dialog.  Then enter user name “DomainName\Username” and password.